# sql track changed values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out what values user changes the most.
I have a user table like this:

[image]

This is a User Table where entries not get changed. If a user changes something, it creates a new record to track what users change.

Now I want to get something like this:

[image]

I want the column names (E-Mail, Phone etc.) as values so I can sort.

Has anyone an idea how I could do that please?

Edit: I'm using SSMS and T-SQL

Comment: I'd have a users table with one row per user, storing current values. Then I'd have a trigger to log changes, (One row per change, storing both old and new values.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm not allowed to make changes to the db.

Comment: @LucienRyter: SSMS is not a "database" or a "DBMS". It's an application that can connect to a SQL Server database to run SQL statements and it is irrelevant for the question

Comment: @LucienRyter you *can't* detect data changes without enabling [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), adding triggers to the table or using a system-versioned table.

Comment: Change tracking is very lightweight and works on all versions and editions and can return either the changed IDs or all rows since the last change. It's transparent to the tables and applications too. Triggers require adding extra tables etc. System-versioned tables require SQL Server 2016 or later

Comment: I cannot figure out the relationship between the desired results and the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Check for example the NumberOfKids values.
It counts how many times people changed this value. 
It doesnt count the first entry (FirstEntry bool)

Comment: Usually we don't care about the total change since the beginning of time (or when we started tracking such things), we care about the trend over time (and perhaps peaks). Think about what you measure, how you record it, and how you intend to use that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks horrible but it works:

```
select * into #q1 from (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY i.CreationDate) rn, i.Email, i.Phone, i.Address, i.Phone, i.NumberOfKids
         FROM   user i) as t

SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN a.Email= b.Email THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Amount, 'Email' as ColumnName
FROM   #q1 a
       JOIN #q1 b
         ON a.UserID= b.UserID
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN a.Address= b.Address THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Amount, 'Address' as ColumnName
FROM   #q1 a
       JOIN #q1 b
         ON a.UserID= b.UserID
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN a.Phone= b.Phone THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Amount, 'Phone' as ColumnName
FROM   #q1 a
       JOIN #q1 b
         ON a.UserID= b.UserID
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN a.NumberOfKids= b.NumberOfKids THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Amount, 'NumberOfKids' as ColumnName
FROM   #q1 a
       JOIN #q1 b
         ON a.UserID= b.UserID
order by Amount desc
drop table #q1
```

Comment: Only if the actual question was different than what you asked. You don't need UNION at all, just a *single* self join, a `WHERE` that checks if any of the other fields have changed